# Are non-independent samples an issue in within groups designs

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, independence

I'm currently designing a statistical analysis. Currently opting for a repeated-measures ANOVA with 4 factors. The data I am using a list of time series. These are grouped by where they came from and also I will be getting a varied number of slices from each series. The within subject design would be comparing between the value at the beginning of each slice and at the end of each slice (2 levels).

My question is: do I need to be worried about the non-independence of samples? My instinct is yes but logically wouldn't any issues of covariance in the IV be corrected as the analysis is only interested in the change within each time series.

Comment: How the non-independence comes to your samples?

Comment: Say I have 10 time series, 3 will be taken from one individual, 3 from another and 4 from another. Within each series, I'll be taking 1-5 slices and using the start and end as the two levels of each factor. Therefore, the different time series are related by who created them and also individual slices are related by being part of the same time series.